# Show that $x^3-p \in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ for $p=2,3$ splits completely or doesnt over $\mathbb{Q}_3$(p^(1/3)) and $\mathbb{Q}_2$(p^(1/3))

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, p-adic-number-theory, splitting-field

I want to show when $x^3-p \in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ for $p=2,3$ splits completely over $\mathbb{Q}_3$(p^(1/3)) and $\mathbb{Q}_2$(p^(1/3))(so its the splitting field) and when it doesn't split.

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing. $\Bbb{Q}_3(p^{1/3})$ is an extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ only, if $p=3$.

Comment: Oh, are you looking at $\Bbb{Q}_2(2^{1/3})$ and $\Bbb{Q}_3(3^{1/3})$? But in that case I don't understand the use of *when*, because there is no variable. If you intended to ask about $x^3-p$ over $\Bbb{Q}_p$, where $p$ is an unknown prime, then it is known that it splits over $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/3})$ if and only if $p\equiv1\pmod3$.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I didnt know how to write third root of p. I wanted to know when and why for those two Extensions youve written that polynomial splits completely. My mistake. Im looking only for primes 2 and 3

Comment: $\zeta_3\in \Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/3})$ iff $\zeta_3\in \Bbb{Q}_p$ iff $\zeta_3\in \Bbb{F}_p$ iff $3|p-1$.

Comment: Thank you,  so for p=2,3 it doesnt